An inequality may fail when $p\in[1,\infty)$ in one dimension by constructing a sequence of smooth functions of the characteristic function
I have read the paper \url{https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.2025254118}, and I am confused about (4.3) in this paper.
Indeed, let $1\leqslant p<\infty$, (4.3) in this paper is stated as follows:
\begin{equation}\label{1}
  \left\|\dfrac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{\frac{2}{p}}}\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})}
  \leqslant C\|u'\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})},\quad \forall u\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}),\tag{*}
\end{equation}
The paper claims that \eqref{1} may fail in the following sense: taking $u=u_n$, a sequence of smooth functions converging to the characteristic function $\chi_I$ of a bounded interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then the right-hand side of \eqref{1} remains bounded while its left-hand side tends to infinity.
My question: I am not sure how to construct the required sequence of smooth fucntions and how to prove that the right-hand side of \eqref{1} remains bounded while its left-hand side tends to infinity. Maybe use the following function (by replacing $\varepsilon$ by $\frac{1}{n}$):
\begin{equation}
  \varphi_\varepsilon(x)
   =\frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\varphi(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  \varphi(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    c\exp(\frac{1}{x^2-1}),   &|x|<1,\\
    0,                        &|x|\geqslant 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
with $c$ is the constant that makes
\begin{equation}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1,
\end{equation}
and convolution to construct the required sequence of smooth functions?
I wish to know more details. Thank you!

You are on the right track. First normalize $\varphi$, $\varphi_\varepsilon$ so that their integral is $1$. Consider
$$ u_n=\chi_I*\varphi_{1/n}. $$
You can compute the derivative explicitly by looking at the definition of convolution:
$$ u_n’(x)=\varphi_{1/n}(x-a)-\varphi_{1/n}(x-b), $$
where $I=(a,b)$. The $L^1$ norm is thus bounded by $2\|\varphi_{1/n}\|_{L^1}= 2\|\varphi\|_{L^1}=2$, which is a constant independent of $n$.
To check that the left hand side blows up, first notice how substituting $u=\chi_I$ makes the norm infinite (you can do the computation). Then, since $u_n$ tends to $u$ pointwise a.e., you can conclude that the left hand side diverges when plugging $u_n$ by Fatou’s lemma:
\begin{align}
  +\infty&=\left\|\dfrac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{\frac{2}{p}}}\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})}\\
&=
 \left\|\liminf_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{u_n(x)-u_n(y)}{|x-y|^{\frac{2}{p}}}\right|\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})}\\
\text{Fatou’s lemma}\;\to\;&\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\left\|\dfrac{u_n(x)-u_n(y)}{|x-y|^{\frac{2}{p}}}\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})}\\
&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\|\dfrac{u_n(x)-u_n(y)}{|x-y|^{\frac{2}{p}}}\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})}\\
&\leq +\infty
\end{align}
$$ \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\dfrac{u_n(x)-u_n(y)}{|x-y|^{\frac{2}{p}}}\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R})}=+\infty. $$
Note that Fatou’s lemma can be used with integrals replaced by $L^p$ norms: just apply the usual Fatou’s lemma to the sequence
$$ f_n(x,y)=\left|\dfrac{u_n(x)-u_n(y)}{|x-y|^{\frac{2}{p}}}\right|^p. $$

Awesome! I have checked all the details. Thank you very much!
